# How to access a method from the main function in java

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
public class Wallgame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Hello();
    }
    public void Hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

This does not work, and I don't know why I can't access the Hello method. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the static/non-static issue, that's not the correct syntax to call a method. You only use `new` when creating an object.

Comment: Not duplicate at all , he just mistake java as javascript ?

Comment: This is a basic foundational knowledge question and is best answered by reading an introductory Java book or tutorial.

Comment: I fixed my problem... I figured out by myself :D. I just did `Hello()` instead of adding `new` and made it a `static void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello method should be static and you call it by writing Hello(); in the main method.

Comment: You also have to change the `public void` to `static void`